# SQL - Create a table with unique date & currency records for every currency code in a table (between two defined dates)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a currency code table with ~40 records and a query that produces a list of dates between two days. (I also have a table, but figured this would work)

The goal is to create a table of every combination of currency and day. So if there are 4 currencies and 10 days there would be 400 records of every combination.

Thanks for any insight!

| PK | Currency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD |
| 2 | EUR |
| 3 | CAD |
| 4 | KRW |
| 5 | CNY |
| 6 | JPY |
| 7 | GBP |
| 8 | PLN |
| 9 | NZD |
| ... | ... |

```
    DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
    
    SET @StartDateTime = Getdate()-15
    SET @EndDateTime = Getdate()-1
    
    
    ;WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
    (
        SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
        FROM DateRange 
        WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
    )
    SELECT CAST(DateData as Date)
    FROM DateRange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross join is what you want.

```
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateData, Currency 
FROM DateRange
CROSS JOIN CurrencyTableName
```

If a column is already a date type you don't have to cast it to Date

Comment: Brilliant, it was right under my nose...
     
```DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime Getdate()-15
SET @EndDateTime = Getdate()-1

;WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)

Select * from DateRange
 CROSS JOIN CURRENCIES```

Comment: @charleface and anyone who cares -- the CROSS JOIN keyword is not needed on all platforms.